# Android Set links clickable in edittext after pasting

Tags: android, url, android-edittext, listener, clickable

I have a note application which supports clickable links. My problem is that links are clickable after I save the note and open it. How I can set the link clickable right after it's pasted? I'm trying to do that with the addTextChangedListener but I can't get it to work.

Comment: What exactly did you try?

Comment: In the afterTextChanged I'm calling these methods:
textData.setLinksClickable(true);
textData.setAutoLinkMask(Linkify.WEB_URLS);

It did not work. Also I tried to clear the editText and set it again but I get stackOverflow (haha)